# Ammending / restating a Living Revocable Trust

Tags: united-states, trusts-and-estates

Imagine a person has setup a living revocable trust. If the trust is amended you would need to keep both the original trust documents and the amendment. (Correct me if I am wrong about this?)

Now imagine there is a second amendment which restates the entire trust. At this point can you throw away the original trust document and the first amendment to the trust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could destroy the previous version, but it would be prudent not to do so, because if there is a dispute over the validity of the restated trust and that is successful, the terms of the trust prior to restatement remain in effect.

Arguably, one could even be accused of spoliation of evidence if there was any remotely possible reason to think that there might be a contest later.

Answer (score 2):

If an amendment restates the entire trust, I have been told by an attorney that you can throw away the original trust documents because they are no longer valid.

Note: I am not an attorney. I do not have any formal training is law so
my answer is not reliable.

Comment: You could, but it would be prudent not to because if there is a dispute over the validity of the restated trust and that is successful, the terms of the trust prior to restatement remain in effect. Arguably, one could even be accused of spoilation of evidence if there was any remotely possible reason to think that there might be a contest later.

Comment: @ohwilleke If you were to post your comment as an answer, I will accept the answer which will close the question.